# correct way to tell if my selection caught any existing elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm making a toggle in d3, and trying to avoid global variables.

I can go ahead and select the item as though it was already in the scene:

```
d3.select('#awesome_line_graph')
```

and then test to see if I caught anything using

```
if (d3.select('#awesome_line_graph')[0].every(function(d){return d===null})){
    // draw awesome line graph
} else {
    d3.select('#awesome_line_graph').remove()
}
```

but this testing for the zeroth element for maybe more than one null thing seems terrible and hacky. How should I do it instead? Apologies for not knowing much javascript.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Use [`selection.empty()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_empty). Also, if the selection is empty, there's no need to remove it.

Comment: Actually it should be `selection.empty()` , it is a function call isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

I highly recommend you read Mike Bostock's [D3 Workshop](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/d3/workshop/)  document.  In it, he talks about how a selection returns an array of elements that match the selection criteria.  Therefore, if the length of the array is greater than "0", you've properly matched and selected.

You may also want to read his documentation on "[Nested Selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/)."  I found it pretty useful.

I hope this helps.

Frank

Answer (score 3):

In version d3.js v5, one can use

```
if(var n = d3.select('#awesome_line_graph').size() == 0) {
  console.log("no DOM element selected.");
} else {
  console.log(n  + " DOM element(s) selected.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using length wont do as a single object containing all results will be returned in either cases. Maybe you could do something like ...

```
var selected = d3.select('#selected');
if (selected._group[0][0] == null) { 
    // nothing found 
} else { 
    // found something 
}
```